# Resetting Google Cloud Platform account

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I use Google App Engine and I have problem: I did something and now the things I installed are not saved in the instance, and I can’t test my code before the deployment, because somehow I installed Python 2.7 there...

In short, I would like to delete all the data from my Google Cloud Platform account to start everything from scratch. How can I do this? Just deleting a project does not help. Data still remains in the folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy an app from scratch into the project without any issues. Not only can you change runtimes from version to version, but even change environments (Flexible, Standard).

Just start in a new local directory of yours, for example.